# How to get a length of a String by using 1 method? SHORTER

Tags: java, string, methods, string-length

It's really easy to get the length of a single string and return it's value!

```
public static int length(String s){//trys and returns length of any string
    try{//try code
    len = s.length();//gets the length of any string
    }catch (NullPointerException nullError){//checks for nulls
        len = 0;//if there is a null then there is 0 length of the string
    }
    return len;//return the integer length of any string
}
```

This simple code will catch an error!
An example of an error would be if you use a JOptionPane and the user doesn't print anything just clicks the X. That would cause a null error!
So if that's the case then then length would just be 0!

But now I just want to know how to make this a shorter code!

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: One of my friends need to know this so I posted this for them and anyone else that wanted to use this! @AmerQarabsa

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to get some tips on how to get the most of the SO community, and what makes for good questions and answers. This particular format isn't really appropriate as a question, since it isn't presenting a problem that someone can answer. Check out the Help Center for tips on getting started. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return str != null ? str.length() : 0`

Comment: Thank you! I need to learn more!

Comment: No problem, everyone's new at some point. Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem. And also, take a minute to read the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are new here. Welcome to SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception on your end.

A **null** string is **null**. It doesn't have a **length**!
An **empty** string has length 0.

And to add more confusion, try what happens when you do

```
String str = null;
System.out.println(str);
```

Surprise ... that will print **more** than just an empty line.

In other words: better think twice before *defining* that a **null** string has length 0!

In that sense, you might better be doing something like

```
public static String ensureNotNull(String input) {
  if (input == null) { return ""; }
  return input;
}

String someString = ... coming from somewhere, maybe null
someString = ensureNotNull(someString);
```

Because **that** will make sure that someString has length 0, and is not null! More importantly: "your" idea is to have A) some string variable B) some additional int variable. Meaning: based on the value of that string, you have to carry along that additional int value. So, all of a sudden, your code dealing with that one string ... also has to deal with that *other* int value. All the time. Not a good idea.

Comment: I'm saying I want the length to be 0 if there is a null. Thank you!

Comment: Please see my updated answer; I think there are **better** ways to deal with that.

Comment: I also need it to be an integer.

Comment: Be careful about wording. There is **int** and **Integer**. But there is no thing such as *integer* in Java.

Comment: Ok I think I know now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GhostCat Integers are very much present in Java. It just doesn't have an *integer* keyword. It's perfectly acceptable (and arguably preferable) to refer to variables of type `int` as integers though. That's what they are (and that's what `int` is short for). `:)`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int length(String s){
   return s==null?0:s.length();
}
```